# Gradle project dependency on a specific configuration

Tags: java, gradle, multi-project

I have a user defined sourcesets (mysourceset) in project A, and in project B want to depend on its output. I tried

`testCompile project(path: ':A', configuration: 'mysourcesetCompile')` but no luck.

Also tried creating a configuration in project A and using it in project B as follows.

```
testCompile project(':A').configurations.myconfig
```

also no luck!

Comment: I solved it with project(':a').files('.'). No better way to solve this: also put the sample code here https://github.com/ghamarian/gradleproblem

Comment: The problem was solved by project(':a').sourceSets.mysourceset.output. Just had to make sure that I use evaluationDependsOn(':a') in b.gradle.